# Adding a check in arguments json_to_set in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

So I have

```
WITH input_students as (select *
        from json_to_recordset(json_data :: json -> 'users')
        as student (organization_id bigint, section text, class text,admission_number text))
```

Now ,  I wanna make sure that the organization_id is not "" (if so , null would be preferable as a value),however I am not able to use  `case when ... then end` inside of arguments (ignore it as a beginner's  mistake if it is one). I haven't found any other resource to fix the bug of handling an empty string scenario. Any help would be appreciated.
I tried doing

```
WITH input_students as (select *
        from json_to_recordset(json_data :: json -> 'users')
        as student (organization_id bigint, section text, class text,admission_number text))
        insert into students select nullif(a.organization_id,''),a.section,a.class ,a.admission_number,'1',2,3,'true' from input_students a;
```

but it provides with an error
`"error": "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: \"\"\n  Where: PL/pgSQL function hsg_put_user_class_section_v2(text) line 22 at SQL statement"`
The function is :

```
create or replace function hsg_put_user_class_section_v2(json_data text)
returns table(org_id bigint,
admission_number text,
status text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    error_organization_id_invalid character varying := 'Organization ID is invalid !';
    error_admission_number_invalid character varying := 'Admission Number is invalid !';
    error_user_does_not_exist character varying := 'User does not exist !';
    error_class_not_found character varying := 'Class not found !';
    error_section_not_found character varying := 'Section not found';
    success_message character varying :='Updated Successfully';
begin
CREATE TEMP TABLE students (
        organization_id bigint,
        section text,
        class text,
        admission_number text,
        admission_number_in_hsg text,
        organization_id_in_hsg bigint,
        user_id bigint,
        status text
        )
        ON COMMIT DROP;
    
        WITH input_students as (select *
        from json_to_recordset(json_data :: json -> 'users')
        as student (organization_id bigint, section text, class text,admission_number text))
        insert into students select nullif(a.organization_id,0),a.section,a.class ,a.admission_number,'1',2,3,'true' from input_students a;
        return query select
                s.organization_id,
                s.admission_number,
                s.status
                from students s;
end;
$function$ ;
```

Comment: Your error doesn't make sense with the rest of your question.  If you are creating a function, you should put that code in here.  However, I would recommend trying to get the query correct _before_ putting it into a function.

Comment: Its only a part of the entire function . what I eventually return is the temporary table `stundents` like `return query SELECT * FROM students`

Comment: Yes, I get that, but without the rest of the function, it's not possible to accurately debug your issue.  The errors you are getting could be related to PL/pgSQL syntax, not SQL.

Comment: Updated with the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, that should be

```
WITH input_students as (
   SELECT *
   FROM json_to_recordset(json_data::json -> 'users')
   AS s(organization_id text,
        section text,
        class text,
        admission_number text)
)
INSERT INTO students
SELECT CAST (nullif(a.organization_id,'') AS bigint),
       a.section,
       a.class,
       a.admission_number,
       '1',
       2,
       3,
       'true'
FROM input_students AS a;
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it provided with an error  , I have updated my question with the solution that I tried.

Comment: Error : `"error": "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: \"\"\n  Where: SQL statement \"WITH input_students as (select *\r\n\t\tfrom json_to_recordset(json_data :: json -> 'users')\r\n\t\tas student (organization_id bigint, section text, class text,admission_number text))\r\n\t\tinsert into students select nullif(a.organization_id,0),a.section,a.class ,a.admission_number,'1',2,3,'true' from input_students a\"\nPL/pgSQL function hsg_put_user_class_section_v2(text) line 22 at SQL statement"`

Comment: Ah. I see, you have empty strings in the JSON. You could have said so. Then you have to use `text` in the CTE, see my answer. Note that this will still fail if there are values that are not empty strings and not numbers either, but I cannot guess what your data look like.

Comment: Yep that checks for empty string .Thank you very much for your help.